# acl9 has_many through implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through, acl9

I got the following deprecation warning on the rails console:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Having additional attributes on the join table of a 
has_and_belongs_to_many association is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3.1. 
Please use a has_many :through association instead.
```

The issue lies with the `roles_users` table that I created following an online step-by-step tutorial.

How do I implement a `has_many :through` association for acl9? It's beyond me, especially since the `user` and `role` models each only use helper methods and no actual `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

This is how they look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
  acts_as_authorization_subject  :association_name => :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authorization_role
end
```

Comment: I put an issue on the github page. Hopefully it will be fixed soon. https://github.com/be9/acl9/issues/39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was later discussed in the comments to this GitHub issue.

User model:

```
acts_as_authorization_subject :association_name => :roles, :join_table_name => :roles_users
```

Role model:

```
acts_as_authorization_role :join_table_name => :roles_users
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, for the record, Rails decided not to deprecate the `:join_table` option for habtm after all, so this went away with a subsequent patch release of Rails - ie. you shouldn't need the options mentioned in the issue if you just upgrade your Rails.